# Access "real" previous value with SQL lag having duplicate entries for same key

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

How would it be possible to a get previous timestamp (or any other key for that matter) when there are multiple entries for the same timestamp in SQL (presto).

This is an ideal example outcome

| user | timestamp | category | previous timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1000 | a |  |
| Mary | 1050 | b | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | a | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | c | 1000 |

however if using `lag(timestamp,1) over (partition by user order by timestamp) as previous_timestamp` you get the following

| user | timestamp | category | previous timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1000 | a |  |
| Mary | 1050 | b | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | a | 1050 |
| Mary | 1050 | c | 1050 |

which makes sense given that `lag()` uses the previous row but it's not the expected outcome. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want each timestamp grouped by user and category?

Comment: No. I want the previous timestamp grouped by user regardless of the category. If there were no categories, or a single one, the lag() would work given that there's just one row per timestamp, but since there are multiple rows per timestamp as there can be multiple categories, as shown in the example, that does not work.

Comment: OK, then how about select distinct user, timestamp from some_table order by user ... and do not care about the category?

Comment: select a.user, a.timestamp, b.category, a.previous_timestamp from (select distinct user, timestamp, lag(timestamp,1) over (partition by user order by timestamp) as previous_timestamp from some_table) a join some_table b on a.user = b.user and a.timestamp = b.timestamp; ... this is just typed down and not tested ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for SQL Server, but the logic should work.

```
declare @some_table table (
  [user] varchar(5),
  [timestamp] int,
  [category] varchar(5)
)

insert @some_table
values 
  ('Mary', 1000, 'a')
, ('Mary', 1050, 'b')
, ('Mary', 1050, 'a')
, ('Mary', 1050, 'c')

select *
from @some_table

;
with a1 as (
  select distinct [user]
  , [timestamp]
  from @some_table
),
a2 as (
  select distinct [user]
  , [timestamp]
  , lag([timestamp],1) over (partition by [user] order by [timestamp]) as previous_timestamp
  from a1
)

select a.[user]
, a.[timestamp]
, b.category
, a.previous_timestamp

from (
    select [user]
    , [timestamp]
    , lag([timestamp],1) over (partition by [user] order by [timestamp]) as previous_timestamp
    from a1
  ) a 
  join @some_table b on a.[user] = b.[user] 
                 and a.[timestamp] = b.[timestamp];
```

Comment: Very ingenious! Works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In [Trino version](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html) you can use improved support for [frame type RANGE](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html#-full-support-for-frame-type-range) (which allows to use previous rows that are at least 1 less then current ones):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user, timestamp, category) AS (
 values ('Mary', 1000, 'a'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'b'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'a'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'c')
)

-- query
select user,
    timestamp,
    max(timestamp) over(partition by user order by timestamp RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
from dataset;
```

Output:

| user | timestamp | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1000 | NULL |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |

If this feature is not available in Presto version run by Athena, then you can use approach a bit derived from gaps-and-islands but instead of creating groups and summing values you will set "lag" value to null if it is equal to current one and then use `max` which will ignore nulls:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user, timestamp, category) AS (
 values ('Mary', 1000, 'a'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'b'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'a'),
    ('Mary', 1050, 'c'),
    ('Mary', 1051, 'c'),
    ('Mary', 1051, 'c'),
    ('Mary', 1052, 'c')
),
-- query parts
with_lag as (
    select user,
        timestamp,
        lag(timestamp) over(partition by user order by timestamp) lag_t -- "ordinary" lag
    from dataset
),
with_lag_nulls as (
    select *,
       if(lag_t is null, timestamp, if(lag_t != timestamp, lag_t)) actual_for_lag -- if lag is null use current, if current is not equal to lag, use lag
    from with_lag
)

select user,
       timestamp,
       if(
           lag_t is null, 
           null, -- null for first row in partition
           max(actual_for_lag) over(partition by user order by timestamp)) -- then use max "adjusted" lag  
from with_lag_nulls;
```

Output:

| user | timestamp | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1000 | NULL |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |
| Mary | 1050 | 1000 |
| Mary | 1051 | 1050 |
| Mary | 1051 | 1050 |
| Mary | 1052 | 1051 |